# ESLint Question: Standard guide, or a popular style guide

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, google-style-guide

As a beginner should I be using a standard guide, a popular style guide or should I be working on creating my own file based on my own preferences?

Comment: Up to you what you do. I personally start with the recommended options and add more options. But the recommended are perfectly serviceable. The pre-made settings are also perfectly serviceable. You can always override any rule you don't like.

Comment: [this page](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html) is a good read when considering a standards library.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, standard guides ever at any level. It's about common rules that everybody knows and understands. And at the end of the day, makes the code more comprehensible.

it's the same approach behind frameworks, makes general rules and standards for everyone that are easy to follow.

Comment: Thank You, this is a perfect answer and very helpful.